# Efficient way to do series of image processing tasks serially and save them in document folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have to apply 40 different image processing tasks serially on the same image and then save every output image in the documents folder. So most efficient way to do that is to create a serial queue and just call every block/method for each task? Is it the fastest and the most efficient way to do it? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t effectProcessingQueue;

self.effectProcessingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("effectProcessing", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(self.effectProcessingQueue, 0), ^(void){ 
  //Doing heavy tasks
  [self task1];
});
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(self.effectProcessingQueue, 0), ^(void){ 
  //Doing heavy tasks
  [self task2];
});
 .
 .
 .
 .
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
 //Doing some UI update in main thread after all the tasks are done. 
});
```

Comment: Do serial image processing tasks in one queue with one block in a for loop and call dispatch_async to a different queue for writing to file. This way your cpu will always work for image processing and you don't have to be blocked by writing to disk.

Comment: Thanks, What queue do you suggest for saving rendered images? I assume you meant a global queue for saving images right? and should i use any QOS too? @YunusErenGüzel

Comment: Using a global queue should be fine. You can also check NSOperationQueue to have more control on async tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much. @YunusErenGüzel